# Argument missing after: "-c" vim error after git show

Tags: git, vim

I have been using vim as an editor for vim for a long time now. I set vim as the default editor by:

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

But now git show stoped to work. If I call

```
git show a802fa69:path_to_file/file.cpp
```

I get the error message

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep 19 2018 08:30:40)
Argument missing after: "-c"
More info with: "vim -h"
```

Any ideas? What does Argument missing after: "-c" mean? How can I fix it? It was working previously...

Comment: `git show` doesn't open an editor (at least not for me), it directly prints the diff to the terminal. Only commands like `commit` and `rebase -i` open the configured editor. It might be worthwhile to check the process tree (from git to Vim) including command-line arguments to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not default git show behavior. Check your `.gitconfig` to see if `git show` is redefined. You might also check your aliases and `.bashrc`. It seems like vim is being called by one of these settings with the `-c` flag, but no command is given. For instance, `vim -c` will raise the same error.